# Android - How to use included library projects in your main and call their activities

Tags: android, android-activity, include, project

I've got a few projects Im trying to combine into one and Ive already included all the other projects as library ones through the settings. What Im sort of stuck on is how to use them in my main activity.

Ive messed around and feel like Ive almost got it but Im just stuck. I know I have to declare all the new activities in the main manifest but Im not sure about what to include in the main .java activity inorder to call from the newly included stuff.

Is this something that I could figure out by looking at the android api demos that come with the sdk?

Can some one point me to an open source project somewhere and explain the process used to include the library projects.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ok so I have figured that.....yes you can see an example of how to include activities inside the ApiDemoManifest.xml file from the samples included with the sdk.  However now I need to figure out how to use the included activities in the main activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using eclipse to manage your settings?  It doesnt really matter, but its easier to make sure your library paths are set correctly and are accessible by the calling project.

Assuming that they are accessible, you just access the classes in the library like any other class:  Import the package and instantiate the class as you would normally.  For an android activity, this means that you would likely create an activity from the library based on some response from your main activity. It doesn't matter if that Activity is local to this project or imported from a library. eg:

```
// import the activity/package/class from your library
import com.mylibrary.activities.ImportedActivity;


public class LocalActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Button Code
        button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // create a new intent based on your library activity
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ImportedActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });
}
```

note, I have not tried to compile the code above, its just for purposes of demonstration.

If your libraries are correctly referenced in eclipse, this should work.  If not you will get errors on either the import of the external libraries (package not found) or build errors when the actual library is needed.

Comment: Ok cool....yes Im using eclipse. So all I have to do is include the packages from the libraries ive imported with import statements and then I should be able to launch their activities by using an intent?

Comment: Yes, I should mention however that for you will need to declare all the activities you plan to use in your manifest file.  No different than you would if the activities were created locally, but this step is often overlooked. eg: `<activity android:name="com.mylibrary.activities.ImportedActivity"></activity>`

Comment: Awesome man. Ill try this out when I get back and let you know how I do. For some reason I was under the assumption that it was going to be much more complicated than that :P

Comment: Ok so I tried out something similar to the code you used as an example up above but its not performing the correct action to get the activity to launch. Do I have to set a return activity or something?

Comment: Did you add the activity to the manifest file of the library? eg: `<manifest>
  ...
  <application>
    ...
    <activity android:name="LibraryActivity" />
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>`

Comment: take a look here for a good example: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html Specifically the setting up a library project, and referencing a library project sections.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help dude I havent looked that up yet but Ill be checking it out when I get a chance next